# How to return a "noop" document over HTTP

Tags: javascript, cgi

I have a CGI script that does a lot things.  I'm trying to keep the script very simple and portable.  I just need some way for the user to send a message to the server without having to lose the current page.  So far, I have the following process:

1. User loads a "status page" from a CGI script.
2. The status page has a javascript timer that will read data (not the entire page) from the server every two seconds and alter the status page accordingly.
3. User clicks a hyperlink element to launch a job on the server.
4. The CGI receives the parameters from the click and starts the job.
5. The CGI sends a response of `\n`

At this point Firefox asks the user if they want to download the CGI script and of course the script is just the `\n` that the CGI sent.  Instead, I want the browser to ignore the response altogether.  If my CGI script does not echo a `\n` apache gives an error.  What could I do to tell the browser to ignore the response and stay on the current page?  Note that I would rather not reload the current page.  I'm thinking there must be some sort of "noop" HTTP response for such a case.

Comment: @Noon: The term [NOOP](http://ftpguide.com/NOOP.htm) is [just as valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

Comment: How about a compromise:  NO½P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send back a response with the 204 HTTP status code. From [RFC 2616 aka Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request
>   but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return
>   updated metainformation. The response
>   MAY include new or updated
>   metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present
>   SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it
>   SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to
>   be sent. This response is primarily
>   intended to allow input for actions to
>   take place without causing a change to
>   the user agent's active document view,
>   although any new or updated
>   metainformation SHOULD be applied to
>   the document currently in the user
>   agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to solve this problem on the server side, you might want to investigate a client side solution. For example, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you can easily initiate an [AJAX asynchronous request](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to the server on a button click. You don't have to load a new page on the browser at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the hyperlink be a real `<a>` or `<form>` with default behavior, have it be some clickable element whose clicks are handled by your client-side code. The Javascript code should send the job requests with XMLHttpRequest objects, putting it in complete control of how the response is handled.

Comment: I have considered that and I'm sure it would work.  However, the CGI script has a lot of layers just to get the link to appear.  AJAX or jQuery would make it quite ugly compared to having a simple HTTP response that the browser ignores.

Comment: @User1 well the problem is that the semantics of HTTP simply do not provide for what you're asking.  When you click a link (or post a form) using the plain ol' browser basic behaviors, then come Hell or high water the browser expects to load something to replace the current page.

Comment: @User1 well I guess I learn something every day :-)  Thanks for asking the question!! Still, as soon as you need to have your server return a response to indicate whether it is *possible* to start the requested job, you'll be back to XMLHttpRequest.